How to solve react hydration error in Nextjs with Chakra UI
I am learning to use Nextjs with Chakra UI in building website. However, when I am about to finish, there is this error:

I assume is has something to do with the dark mode? I have been modifying the code to not to use dark mode. How can I solve it? I am just starting to learn Nextjs.
page.tsx
import { Box, Grid, GridItem, Theme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Main from "./views/Main";
import About from "./views/About";
import Tech from "./views/Tech";
import Projects from "./views/ProjectView";
import Certificates from "./views/CertificateView";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Theme appearance="light">
      <Box className="main-container">
        <Box className="main-header-container">
          <Main />
        </Box>
        <Box className="grid-container">
          <Grid
            w="100%"
            templateRows="auto"
            templateColumns={{
              base: "1fr", // Single column for mobile and tablet
              lg: "repeat(4, 1fr)", // Four columns for desktop and larger
            }}
            gap={2}
          >
            <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 1, lg: 3 }} className="grid-item">
              <About />
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 1, lg: 1 }} className="grid-item">
              <Tech />
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 1, lg: 2 }} className="grid-item">
              <Projects />
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 1, lg: 2 }} className="grid-item">
              <Certificates />
            </GridItem>
          </Grid>
        </Box>
        <Footer />
      </Box>
    </Theme>
  );
}

layout.tsx
import "./globals.css";
import { Provider } from "@/components/ui/provider";
import Footer from "./components/Footer"

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </head>
      <body suppressHydrationWarning >
        <Provider>
          {children}
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

provider.tsx
"use client"
import { ChakraProvider, defaultSystem } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import {
  ColorModeProvider,
  type ColorModeProviderProps,
} from "./color-mode"

export function Provider(props: ColorModeProviderProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider value={defaultSystem}>
      <ColorModeProvider {...props} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

